# Looping Over a 2D Array to Change All Elements in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array that acts as a "game board" for a word search project I am creating: `var gameBoard = Array(rows){ Array(cols){ "." } }`. My question is: how do I loop over each element of the array and replace its value? I am wanting something like `if gameBoard[row][col] == ".", then gameBoard[row][col] = A-Z.random()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the idea of 2D Arrays

```
val a = arrayOf<Int>(1, 2)
val b = arrayOf<Int>(3, 4)

val c: Array<Array<Int>> = arrayOf(a, b)

for (i in 0 until c.size) {
    for (j in 0 until c[i].size) {
        c[i][j] = 100 //just an example
    }
}
```

And if you print out the values like so:

```
for (i in 0 until c.size) {
    for (j in 0 until c[i].size) {
        d("TAG", "the value at " + i.toString() + "-" + j.toString() + " is: " + c[i][j].toString())
    }
}
```

You get this output:

```
the value at 0-0 is: 100
the value at 0-1 is: 100
the value at 1-0 is: 100
the value at 1-1 is: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a [List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/) instead of an [Array](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/) :-)

```kotlin
val gameboardInitial = List(4) { List(3) { "." } }
val gameboardFinal = gameboardInitial.map { 
  it.map { 
    when (it) {
      "."  -> ('A'..'Z').random()
      else -> it
    }
  }
}

println(gameboardFinal)
```

See the [fiddle](https://pl.kotl.in/wrXbx3TjI).